# $.when().done not working on blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to run a validation check and need to call the database and get result before I proceed, I am using ajax promise handler to wait for the response but for some reason it execution flow does not stop.

```
 $("#attr").blur(function() {
        var attrValue = $("#attr").val();
        if (attr.length > 256) {
            $("#Validation").text(" has a max of 256 characters");
            $("#Validation").show();
            $("#attr").focus();
        } else {
            if (attrValue.length > 0) {
                $.when(check_attribute_name(attrValue)).done(function (data) {
                    if (data.result == false) {
                        $("#Validation").text("Another exists with this name. Try again!");
                        $("#Validation").show();
                        $("#attr").focus();
                        $("#unique").val("fasle");
                    } else {
                        $("#attrValidation").hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    function check_attribute_name(attrValue) {
               return $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    url: "@Url.Action("Validation", "validator")",
                    data: { name: attrValue },
            });

    }
```

Comment: Please add the version of jQuery you're using as this may have an impact on what the issue may be. Add the HTML for the page might help as well.

Comment: The logic you are using looks good to me, other than `$.when()` being unnecessary (but not invalid)

Comment: Your code looks ok here. Have you checked the console to ensure that the request is working correctly and there are no server-side errors?

Comment: I am using jquery 1.11.0